# How do I get the bandage in 1-18: Altamont?

Tags: super-meat-boy

How do you can the bandage in 1:18 Altamont, Light World?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get 10 bandages from other levels to unlock Gish (side note: this will also earn you a 5 gamer score achievement). Jump to the lower right platform which is next to the bandage. Inch yourself over the edge and grab the side using Gish special. Allow yourself to slowly side down to grab the bandage and then jump to the fall wall and jump up to get to Bandage girl!

Comment: You can do this with regular Meat Boy as well -- rather than trying to jump back up onto the platform with the bandage, try jumping for the far wall instead.